# How to Get product attribute set id by attribute set name in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, attribute-set

I have a product attribute set name `DSLR`, in frontend page i need to get product collection filtered b this product attribute set

```
$dslrAttributeSetId = $this->getAttributeSetIdByName('DSLR'); //how??
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_set_id', array('eq' => $dslrAttributeSetId));
```

how can i get this product attribute set id by product attribute set name?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code for m1 you can take idea for this code for m2

```
<?php
$attributeSetName = "default"; // put your own attribute set name
$attribute_set = Mage::getModel("eav/entity_attribute_set")->getCollection();
$attribute_set->addFieldToFilter("attribute_set_name", $attributeSetName)->getFirstItem();
echo $attribute_set->getAttributeSetId();
?>
```